# hyperlink in java

Tags: java, swing, hyperlink

Is there any method to create clickable hyperlink in JTextArea in Java?

Answer (score 8):

One way you can do it if you absolutely want to use the jTextArea is to get the User MouseClick(x,y) location and then handle from there.

However, the easier way out would be to use a JEditorPane. Maybe this link will help:

http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Swing-Tutorial/Swing-Tutorial-JEditorPane.html

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks! Just hoping to help (: Cheers!