# Java: Click on Text in TextArea and have it call a function

Tags: java, swing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [hyperlink in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866281/hyperlink-in-java)

First post here on Stack Overflow. 8)

My question is regarding a desktop client JAVA program, not JavaScript or any web-based implementation.

The idea I'm after is to have a TextArea (or something that acts like one) have "hyperlinks" that users can click on.  These hyperlinks under the hood would call a predefined Java function.

I know I can create clickable JLabels and similar things, but I'm after a paragraph style text with a single clickable word that runs a function.

Is there a way to make text in a TextArea have this sort of behavior?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

`JTextPane` would be the component you want.
You will get a clear idea from this oracle [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can usee a `JEditorPane`, and an HTML document as the source of your text and add a `HyperlinkListener` to the editor. In this case you will also have to create "fictive" URLs for the links.

Another option is to use a `JTextPane`, write some code to provide the "hyperlink" highlighting, and add a mouse listener to check for user clicks on the links.